# Linebreaks with knitr

Tags: r, latex, knitr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding a line break to code blocks in R Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306745/adding-a-line-break-to-code-blocks-in-r-markdown)

Is there any option in knitr to preserve linebreaks in R code? After compiling the document, the code should be displayed like in the following example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

<<hist>>=
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100,100,20))
library(lattice)
histogram(~x,
      df,
      main="histogram",
      nint=20)
@ 

\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: was just asked a few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11306745/559676

Comment: your're right. It's a bit embarrassing. I should have been able to answer this question by myself if I read your documentation more carefully. The next time...

Comment: that is fine; I understand the documentation is too long :) I think you can accept the answer by @csgillespie below.

Comment: @George Stocker, Actually, this is about linebreaks all around, whereas the other is about breaking on specific lines.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`knitr` automatically tidies the R code. So to get line breaks, set `tidy=FALSE`, i.e.

```
<<hist, tidy=FALSE>>=
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100,100,20))
library(lattice)
histogram(~x,
      df,
      main="histogram",
      nint=20)
@
```

Comment: ... and then, if you'll be using knitr, go browse the well-organized documentation at http://yihui.name/knitr/options to see the full collection of chunk and package options